# U-Boot boot-up fail in BeagleboneBlack using my own compiled kernel image?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, beagleboneblack, u-boot, buildroot

I'm trying to compile the kernel using Buildroot based on the tutorial below: http://free-electrons.com/doc/training/buildroot/buildroot-labs.pdf .

I follow all the steps strictly and when I insert the SD card into BeagleboneBlack (powered by USB cable), choose to boot from SD Card, the boot is not successful. The output of the console is as followed:

```
    U-Boot 2017.09 (Sep 27 2017 - 17:41:38 +0200)

CPU  : AM335X-GP rev 2.1
I2C:   ready
DRAM:  512 MiB
No match for driver 'omap_hsmmc'
No match for driver 'omap_hsmmc'
Some drivers were not found
MMC:   OMAP SD/MMC: 0, OMAP SD/MMC: 1
<ethaddr> not set. Validating first E-fuse MAC
Net:   cpsw, usb_ether
Press SPACE to abort autoboot in 2 seconds
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
SD/MMC found on device 0
reading boot.scr
** Unable to read file boot.scr **
reading uEnv.txt
98 bytes read in 4 ms (23.4 KiB/s)
Loaded env from uEnv.txt
Importing environment from mmc0 ...
Running uenvcmd ...
** Bad device 0:1 0x82000000 **
reading ramdisk.gz
** Unable to read file ramdisk.gz **
** Bad device 0:1 0x88000000 **
** Bad device 0:1 0x88000000 **
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
Scanning mmc 0:1...
reading /am335x-boneblack.dtb
35712 bytes read in 10 ms (3.4 MiB/s)
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
SD/MMC found on device 0
** File not found /zImage **
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc1(part 0) is current device
Scanning mmc 1:1...
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc1(part 0) is current device
SD/MMC found on device 1
** File not found /zImage **
## Error: "bootcmd_nand0" not defined
starting USB...
USB0:   Port not available.
cpsw Waiting for PHY auto negotiation to complete......... TIMEOUT !
using musb-hdrc, OUT ep1out IN ep1in STATUS ep2in
MAC 98:84:e3:ae:c4:12
HOST MAC de:ad:be:af:00:00
RNDIS ready
musb-hdrc: peripheral reset irq lost!
high speed config #2: 2 mA, Ethernet Gadget, using RNDIS
USB RNDIS network up!
BOOTP broadcast 1
BOOTP broadcast 2
BOOTP broadcast 3
BOOTP broadcast 4
BOOTP broadcast 5
BOOTP broadcast 6
BOOTP broadcast 7
BOOTP broadcast 8
BOOTP broadcast 9
BOOTP broadcast 10
BOOTP broadcast 11
BOOTP broadcast 12
BOOTP broadcast 13
BOOTP broadcast 14
BOOTP broadcast 15
BOOTP broadcast 16
BOOTP broadcast 17
BOOTP broadcast 18
BOOTP broadcast 19
BOOTP broadcast 20
BOOTP broadcast 21
BOOTP broadcast 22
BOOTP broadcast 23
BOOTP broadcast 24
BOOTP broadcast 25
BOOTP broadcast 26
BOOTP broadcast 27
BOOTP broadcast 28
BOOTP broadcast 29

Retry time exceeded; starting again
missing environment variable: pxeuuid
Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/01-98-84-e3-ae-c4-14
using musb-hdrc, OUT ep1out IN ep1in STATUS ep2in
MAC 98:84:e3:ae:c4:12
HOST MAC de:ad:be:af:00:00
RNDIS ready
high speed config #2: 2 mA, Ethernet Gadget, using RNDIS
USB RNDIS network up!
*** ERROR: `serverip' not set
Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/00000000
using musb-hdrc, OUT ep1out IN ep1in STATUS ep2in
MAC 98:84:e3:ae:c4:12
HOST MAC de:ad:be:af:00:00
RNDIS ready
high speed config #2: 2 mA, Ethernet Gadget, using RNDIS
USB RNDIS network up!
*** ERROR: `serverip' not set
Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/0000000
using musb-hdrc, OUT ep1out IN ep1in STATUS ep2in
MAC 98:84:e3:ae:c4:12
HOST MAC de:ad:be:af:00:00
RNDIS ready
high speed config #2: 2 mA, Ethernet Gadget, using RNDIS
USB RNDIS network up!
*** ERROR: `serverip' not set
Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/000000
using musb-hdrc, OUT ep1out IN ep1in STATUS ep2in
MAC 98:84:e3:ae:c4:12
HOST MAC de:ad:be:af:00:00
RNDIS ready
high speed config #2: 2 mA, Ethernet Gadget, using RNDIS
USB RNDIS network up!
*** ERROR: `serverip' not set
Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/00000
using musb-hdrc, OUT ep1out IN ep1in STATUS ep2in
MAC 98:84:e3:ae:c4:12
HOST MAC de:ad:be:af:00:00
RNDIS ready
high speed config #2: 2 mA, Ethernet Gadget, using RNDIS
USB RNDIS network up!
*** ERROR: `serverip' not set
Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/0000
using musb-hdrc, OUT ep1out IN ep1in STATUS ep2in
MAC 98:84:e3:ae:c4:12
HOST MAC de:ad:be:af:00:00
RNDIS ready
high speed config #2: 2 mA, Ethernet Gadget, using RNDIS
USB RNDIS network up!
*** ERROR: `serverip' not set
Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/000
using musb-hdrc, OUT ep1out IN ep1in STATUS ep2in
MAC 98:84:e3:ae:c4:12
HOST MAC de:ad:be:af:00:00
RNDIS ready
high speed config #2: 2 mA, Ethernet Gadget, using RNDIS
USB RNDIS network up!
*** ERROR: `serverip' not set
Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/00
using musb-hdrc, OUT ep1out IN ep1in STATUS ep2in
MAC 98:84:e3:ae:c4:12
HOST MAC de:ad:be:af:00:00
RNDIS ready
high speed config #2: 2 mA, Ethernet Gadget, using RNDIS
USB RNDIS network up!
*** ERROR: `serverip' not set
Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/0
using musb-hdrc, OUT ep1out IN ep1in STATUS ep2in
MAC 98:84:e3:ae:c4:12
HOST MAC de:ad:be:af:00:00
RNDIS ready
high speed config #2: 2 mA, Ethernet Gadget, using RNDIS
USB RNDIS network up!
*** ERROR: `serverip' not set
Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/default-arm-am33xx
using musb-hdrc, OUT ep1out IN ep1in STATUS ep2in
MAC 98:84:e3:ae:c4:12
HOST MAC de:ad:be:af:00:00
RNDIS ready
high speed config #2: 2 mA, Ethernet Gadget, using RNDIS
USB RNDIS network up!
*** ERROR: `serverip' not set
Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/default-arm
using musb-hdrc, OUT ep1out IN ep1in STATUS ep2in
MAC 98:84:e3:ae:c4:12
HOST MAC de:ad:be:af:00:00
RNDIS ready
high speed config #2: 2 mA, Ethernet Gadget, using RNDIS
USB RNDIS network up!
*** ERROR: `serverip' not set
Retrieving file: pxelinux.cfg/default
using musb-hdrc, OUT ep1out IN ep1in STATUS ep2in
MAC 98:84:e3:ae:c4:12
HOST MAC de:ad:be:af:00:00
RNDIS ready
high speed config #2: 2 mA, Ethernet Gadget, using RNDIS
USB RNDIS network up!
*** ERROR: `serverip' not set
Config file not found
starting USB...
USB0:   Port not available.
using musb-hdrc, OUT ep1out IN ep1in STATUS ep2in
MAC 98:84:e3:ae:c4:12
HOST MAC de:ad:be:af:00:00
RNDIS ready
high speed config #2: 2 mA, Ethernet Gadget, using RNDIS
USB RNDIS network up!
BOOTP broadcast 1
BOOTP broadcast 2
BOOTP broadcast 3
BOOTP broadcast 4
BOOTP broadcast 5
BOOTP broadcast 6
BOOTP broadcast 7
BOOTP broadcast 8
BOOTP broadcast 9
BOOTP broadcast 10
BOOTP broadcast 11
BOOTP broadcast 12
BOOTP broadcast 13
BOOTP broadcast 14
BOOTP broadcast 15
BOOTP broadcast 16
BOOTP broadcast 17
BOOTP broadcast 18
BOOTP broadcast 19
BOOTP broadcast 20
BOOTP broadcast 21
BOOTP broadcast 22
BOOTP broadcast 23
BOOTP broadcast 24
BOOTP broadcast 25
BOOTP broadcast 26
BOOTP broadcast 27
BOOTP broadcast 28
BOOTP broadcast 29

Retry time exceeded; starting again
using musb-hdrc, OUT ep1out IN ep1in STATUS ep2in
MAC 98:84:e3:ae:c4:12
HOST MAC de:ad:be:af:00:00
RNDIS ready
high speed config #2: 2 mA, Ethernet Gadget, using RNDIS
USB RNDIS network up!
BOOTP broadcast 1
BOOTP broadcast 2
BOOTP broadcast 3
BOOTP broadcast 4
BOOTP broadcast 5
BOOTP broadcast 6
BOOTP broadcast 7
BOOTP broadcast 8
BOOTP broadcast 9
BOOTP broadcast 10
BOOTP broadcast 11
BOOTP broadcast 12
BOOTP broadcast 13
BOOTP broadcast 14
BOOTP broadcast 15
BOOTP broadcast 16
BOOTP broadcast 17
BOOTP broadcast 18
BOOTP broadcast 19
BOOTP broadcast 20
BOOTP broadcast 21
BOOTP broadcast 22
BOOTP broadcast 23
BOOTP broadcast 24
BOOTP broadcast 25
BOOTP broadcast 26
BOOTP broadcast 27
BOOTP broadcast 28
BOOTP broadcast 29

Retry time exceeded; starting again
=>
```

Here is what I write in uEnv.txt file:

```
bootdir=
bootpart=0:1
uenvcmd=run loadimage;run loadramdisk;run findfdt;run loadfdt;run mmcloados
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong (as specific as possible)? It seems that maybe the boot can't find the zImage but in the /boot partition, I do have zImage file.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong (as specific as possible)?

It looks like the U-Boot environment for booting is inconsistent with what's on the SDcard.
The default U-Boot environment is setup to load kernel, DT blob or FIT images from the **/boot** directory of second partition of the SDcard.  The modifications to load instead from the first partition (i.e. the **uEnv.txt** file) are only partially effective.

You claim :

> ... but in the /boot partition, I do have zImage file.

(**/boot** would be a directory not a *"partition"*.)
Assuming the above is accurate, then the full path for the kernel image file is **/boot/zImage** in the root filesystem.
But the boot log is reporting that

```
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
SD/MMC found on device 0
** File not found /zImage **
```

which means that the kernel is looking in the root directory, **/** of the first partition, rather than in **/boot** of a root filesystem.
Your SDcard probably has a FAT fs in the first partition, rather than an ext3/4 root filesystem.

However the boot log does indicate that the Device Tree blob was found in the root directory, **/**

```
switch to partitions #0, OK
mmc0 is current device
Scanning mmc 0:1...
reading /am335x-boneblack.dtb
35712 bytes read in 10 ms (3.4 MiB/s)
```

Typically the kernel file is stored with the DT blob (in the same directory).
<s>But you seem to have split these two files apart.</s>

Either store both files in the root directory, **/** of the FAT filesystem (as well a missing **ramdisk.gz**),
OR
fix the load commands and path in the environment *and* install the root filesystem in another partition on the SDcard.
The former is easiest (i.e. copy **zImage**).
The solution requires studying the environment variables for the proper changes (e.g. perhaps `bootdir=/boot` in **uEnv.txt** is part of the fix).

---

**UPDATE**

I reviewed U-Boot 2017.09 and the default environment it would build for your board.  The suspicious environment variable is

```
 bootcmd_legacy_mmc0=setenv mmcdev 0; setenv bootpart 0:2 ; run mmcboot
```

where `setenv bootpart 0:2` specifies that the rootfs partition (rather than the VFAT/"boot" partition) is the source partition.
This setenv will override the `bootpart=0:1` that was assigned when the **uEnv.txt** file was read and evaluated.
Conversely the default `bootdir=/boot` that specifies the **/boot** directory for files is overridden by the `bootdir=` from the **uEnv.txt** file.

The net result is that when the **mmcboot** and its **loadimage** variables are run, the **zImage** will be loaded from the root directory of the rootfs, which fails because that file is in the **/boot** directory.

> SD/MMC found on device 0
>       ** File not found /zImage **

Note that the "SD/MMC found on device 0" message prior to the load error is from the `echo` command in the **mmcboot** variable:

```
mmcboot=mmc dev ${mmcdev}; setenv devnum ${mmcdev}; setenv devtype mmc; \
  if mmc rescan; then \
    echo SD/MMC found on device ${mmcdev}; \
    if run loadimage; then \
      if test ${boot_fit} -eq 1; \
        then run loadfit; \          
        else run mmcloados; \
      fi; \
    fi; \
  fi;
```

**Workaround**

A. To load from the first partition, modify variable **bootcmd_legacy_mmc0** to load **zImage** with the current definition of **bootpart**, i.e. do not redefine it.  Either edit the U-Boot source code and rebuild, or use the following U-Boot commands (*after* aborting autoboot, *before* boot fails):

```
setenv bootcmd_legacy_mmc0 'setenv mmcdev 0\; run mmcboot'
bootd
```

OR

B. Modify the **uEnv.txt** file.  Simply insert a new first line:

```
devtype=mmc
```

---

---

**ADDENDUM**

> It is indeed the version incompatibility issue.

If you insist on using U-Boot 2017.09, then Workaround B should suffice.

U-Boot 2016.03 has `loadimage=load mmc ${bootpart} ...`, whereas
U-Boot 2017.09 has `loadimage=load ${devtype} ${bootpart} ...`.
The variable **devtype** is undefined when the **uenvcmd** is run from the **uEnv.txt** file.  Consequently the newer version of U-Boot generates error messages

> ** Bad device 0:1 0x82000000 **
>       ** Bad device 0:1 0x88000000 **
>       ** Bad device 0:1 0x88000000 **

Workaround B ensures **devtype** is defined when the **uenvcmd** is run, so the `load` command accesses the `mmc` device just like the older version.

Comment: Thank you for your support, but it still doesn't fix my problem. I have two partitions: one named "boot" and another named "rootfs". I do save the DT blob and kernel image zImage in the same bootable partition named "boot" (it is /zImage and /-boneblack.dtb in the "boot" parition). And I didn't have any file named ramdisk.gz in my output compile kernel using buildroot. It is weird that the U-boot can't find the /zImage? Is there any other possible problem? Can you please take a little bit look at the tutorial link? I follow exactly what is written there. Maybe something is mistaken.

Comment: @NguyễnThanhVũ *"I follow exactly what is written there."* -- That's not true.  The document states `You can keep using the default 2016.03 version as the U-Boot version.`  There is no mention in the doc about the 2017.09 version that you actually used.  So you did not follow exactly as what is written.  *"Maybe something is mistaken."* -- Maybe. Please try the workarounds.

Comment: It is indeed the version incompatibility issue. Thank you for your help.